# Videos stopped playing on every website

Tags: 12.04, video, google-chrome, flash, chromebook

I have an HP chrome-book 14. I've installed the Ubuntu 12.4 OS on it so I could begin learning to code. Because I prefer the Chrome browser, I've also installed Google Chrome stable (Version 35.0.1916.114). Everything has worked smoothly for the last couple months, but last night video stopped working on all websites. When I switch to Firefox, videos "sometimes" play, but are stopping frequently. I've researched similar issues on this forum and others, but none of the solutions provided (clearing browser data/caches, opening windows in incognito mode, making sure I have an updated Shockwave flashplayer version and that no other flashplayers or media players are interfering, making sure the chrome browser is updated, have worked. I've even uninstalled and re-installed the chrome browser, and have also reset the browser, but it still won't play videos.

When I go to YouTube, or any other site with imbedded video for that matter, it will play the video for what seems a millisecond, but not play past that part. There is NO white/gray/black screen or anything else. It simply stops after I first start the video. What is interesting is that when I switch from Ubuntu back to the default Chromebook, videos play fine. So I'm thinking this may be an Ubuntu issue. Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with diagnosing driver issues, if that is the problem. I should also add that internet speed is fine. No issues there.

Comment: Is that problem only found in google chrome or to all other web browser like firefox??

Answer (score 1):

Flash is an application made by Adobe that displays movies, games, or other content within a web browser. It’s an old web standard that’s slowly being phased out by HTML5 — however, many websites still use Flash plugins for videos, games, and tools. Google Chrome is a browser made by, well, Google (you know, the search engine giant), and it has nearly half of the current marketshare, including support for themes, extensions and HTML5. While Chrome scores higher on browser tests than its competitors, it does have some known issues with Flash — and here’s how to fix them.

First off, issues with Flash games and the such — those can’t be fixed. Chrome and Flash games don’t play well together, for whatever reason — even if Flash is working perfectly fine — so for those, you should definitely go to Mozilla Firefox or another browser to enjoy some flash gaming. For your normal Flash video issues — like lagging and crashing — here’s where you need to go.

First, type about:plugins in your Chrome address bar and press Enter to view what plugins you have installed and are running.

This is where the Flash plugins are stored.

How To Stop The Plugin Conflict

Search for Flash in the plugins list and then check if it says (2 files) in parenthesis beside it.
If it says two files, that means two different installations of Flash — one on your system and one just for the Chrome installation — are conflicting, and that’s where your problem lies.

How To Stop The Plugin Conflict

Search for Flash in the plugins list and then check if it says (2 files) in parenthesis beside it.
If it says two files, that means two different installations of Flash — one on your system and one just for the Chrome installation — are conflicting, and that’s where your problem lies.

Click the + sign next to Details and use the Location tags to determine where each installation is located. Disable the one off your home directory.

If Issues Persist

First, re-activate the Chrome plugin and turn off the operating system plugin. (The opposite of the steps above.)
If that doesn’t fix your issue, deactivate each of your extensions and start Chrome again — an easy way to go about this is to open up an incognito window with extensions disabled. To open up an incognito window, click Chrome’s Menu icon and select Open Incognito Window from the drop down box. By default, incognito starts without extensions. Go to a flash-based page and see if you have any issues. If you don’t, good job — one of your extensions is causing the problem.

To solve this, open up your list of Extensions and one by one, re-enable them while viewing how they effect your Flash performance. To open the list of extensions, open your menu once more, hover over Tools and click Extensions. When you’ve determined which one has been causing you all this trouble, delete or disable it.

Source: http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2013/03/fix-adobe-flash-problems-in-google-chrome/